# How to access an object in a Wikipedia API, if the other objects names/keys keeps changing but the object to be accessed name/key remains the same?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I want to obtain imaged from a Wikipedia API. I am doing front end development so I have to only `"GET"`  the images, no back end.

This is the general API:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:Title_to_be_inserted_hered.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

When a title is inserted after `image:`, a list of objects is returned including the url of the image, which would later be inserted in the webpage.

However, after trying three titles (Italy, Einstein and Obama), the returned objects parameters are different, yet the URL object is always there.

You can notice that what comes after "Pages object" always changes.

Obama:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:obama.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

Italy:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:italy.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

Einstein:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image:einstein.jpg&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

All I want is to grab the URL (using Ajax or JSON) and store into a variable in my script file.

Comment: It's the pageid. As you are requesting only a single page, you can ignore it and just access whatever it is.

Comment: Does my answer not answer the question?

Comment: @mevius it does, thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). For example:

```
var pages = obj.query.pages,  // Get the pages object
    firstPage = pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]],  // Get the first page in the pages object
    src = firstPage.imageinfo[0].url;  // Get the first image url from the page above
```

Here's an actual example with the data from one of your examples:

```js
var data = {"continue":{"iistart":"2007-04-19T23:10:16Z","continue":"||"},"query":{"normalized":[{"from":"Image:obama.jpg","to":"File:Obama.jpg"}],"pages":{"10783885":{"pageid":10783885,"ns":6,"title":"File:Obama.jpg","imagerepository":"local","imageinfo":[{"url":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7a/Obama.jpg","descriptionurl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Obama.jpg","descriptionshorturl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=10783885"}]}}}};

var pages = data.query.pages,
    src = pages[Object.keys(pages)[0]].imageinfo[0].url;

document.write(src);
```

Substituting any of the API responses in for `data` will still return the first url in `imageinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like pretty straightforward JSON structure on all 3 of those urls to me.

The structure is always

```
query -> pages -> imageinfo -> url
```

The information in the results does seem to change a bit, but the full image url seems to be under the same JSON structure as shown above.